# Trouble with spaces in query to elasticsearh

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm experiencing trouble with requesting fileds making requests on field with spaces. Mapping looks like this:

```
"myIndexName": {
    "mappings": {
        "myType": {
            "properties": {
                "myPropertyWithSpaces": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There "analyzer_keyword" is cutom analyzer with keyword tokenizer and lowercase filter.
When I'm sending "_analyze" request with "analyzer_keyword" analyzer and query like "firstWord secondWord" I get only token "firstword secondword" - everything works as expected. But querystring request returns nothing if I don't change space character to "?" wildcard; interesting, that lowercasing still works and such behaviour doesn't change if I'm telling elasticsearch to use this "analyzer_keyword" explicitly.

```
"query": {
"query_string": {
    "query": "firstWord secondWord",
    "default_field": "myPropertyWithSpaces",
    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution in simple escaping space character as "\ ". Works correctly and prevents queryString processor from injecting any "AND OR" operators or whatever.